# How To Fix Xcode Build Failed For IOS Automation

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, testautomationfx

When Using "Build" For Xcode, Build Failed Shows Up. I use Xcode Version 9.4

I have reinstalled xcode already but this does not work

```
"CompileC /Users/dpua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dsupbvdgiqknxbghepgvmbuymtic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/XCUIElement+FBClassChain.o WebDriverAgentLib/Categories/XCUIElement+FBClassChain.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dpua/Desktop/git/WebDriverAgent
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

error: unknown warning option '-Wno-objc-messaging-id'; did you mean '-Wno-objc-cocoa-api'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1"
```

I expect this to work since it is working before but just today it did not work and build keeps failing with the above error message

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I just uninstall/install xcode and copied a working web driver agent from another laptop to be able to run automation again